# How to create the ServiceNow badge integration Client component file to work with Wavelynx badge reader?

Tags: servicenow, smartcard-reader

How to create the `ServiceNow` badge integration Client component file to work with `Wavelynx` badge reader?

I know it can work with HID 5427ck, but my company is moving away from HID

I need some expert help to on how to get it that client component file to work with other readers like `wavelynx`.